# PuTTY not showing the correct version of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, putty

I am hosting my website on JustHost.com. Recently, I started a Laravel 5.1 project and wanted to upload it to the server. The first problem I ran into was the PHP version. The server was configured to 5.4 version, and Laravel 5.1 requires 5.5.9. When I connect to the server with PuTTY and type "php -v" I get the right version (5.4).

I opened the cpanel and switched the version to 5.6 (JustHost provides only 5.4 and 5.6 beta version of PHP). After I uploaded the project, the homepage opened perfectly. Now, I wanted to run some artisan commands, do some database migrations, seed, etc. Again, I connected with PuTTY, navigated to the project root folder and no artisan command was working. Event "php artisan" was not working. I typed again "php -v" and I got the version 5.2.17.

So, the server is configured on 5.6, website is working, but no artisan command works, and PuTTY shows me the 5.2.17. version. Is the problem with PuTTY or on the server side?

Comment: putty is simply a tool allowing one box to connect to another box and execute command-line commands, it is not PHP-aware, it neither knows nor cares about versions of PHP

Answer (score 1):

It seems you ran `php artisan -v`

5.2.17 is a version of Laravel, not PHP.

`php -v` result looks like:

> PHP 7.0.3-13+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.4.0RC4, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
>       with blackfire v1.9.2, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.

`php artisan -v` result looks like:

> Laravel Framework version 5.2.29
>
> Usage:   command [options] [arguments]
>
> Options:   -h, --help            Display this help message   -q,
>   --quiet           Do not output any message   -V, --version         Display this application version
>         --ansi            Force ANSI output
>         --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output   -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
>         --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under.   -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
>
> .... more commands

Comment: No, I have ran `php -v`. `php artisan -v` is not working too.

Comment: I've updated my post, please look and check again. If you're still sure you're getting `5.2.17` with using `php -v`, please upload full screenshot, so we could find a problem.

Comment: Actually, there is a 5.2.17 on the releases page you linked to. It's between 5.3.4 and 5.2.16.

Comment: Thanks Matt, updated my post. Still, I don't think Emir has Jan 2011 version of PHP installed (but who knows?).